# Variable assignment syntax error in shell

Tags: shell, variable

VALUE=${VAR| |o}

I found this variable assignment in shell script. I can't understand why || sign is used here.

## EDIT

Code given in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287378/variable-assignment-syntax-error-in-shell/287444#comment501035_287381):

```
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/cpf/bin/cpf_logging_helper.sh
STATE=$1
DNS_MASTER=${TEST.DNS.DNS_MASTER:-o}
service status dns > /dev/null
rval=$?
if [ $rval -eq 0 ]
then
    if [ $DNS_MASTER == `hostname -s` ]
    then
        echo "1"
    else
        echo "2"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: In which shell is this supposed to be run?  It is a syntactical error in `bash`.

Comment: Its in bash. So , i changed it to VALUE=${VAR} ,but i wwanted to know the intention of coder. :)

Comment: You should ask the coder then)). Is it obvious from the script what kind of replace/suffix/prefix it could be?

Comment: So would I.  I tried it in `bash` and got a syntax error, and there is no mention of this syntax in the manual page.  Inline replacement syntax is `${var/foo/bar}` to change `foo` to `bar`.

Comment: The construct about which you ask is not present in the sample code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the original coder meant to use the value of `$VAR` or `o` if it is unset. In `bash` this can be achieved by using:

```
VALUE=${VAR:-o}
```

See also `man bash` and search for `Parameter Expansion` or `:-`

Comment: VALUE=${VAR:-o} and VAR is neither defined  in the script nor in the file sourced, i tried and its giving syntax error.

Comment: What is the version of bash you are using?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: #!/bin/bash
source /opt/cpf/bin/cpf_logging_helper.sh

STATE=$1

 DNS_MASTER=${TEST.DNS.DNS_MASTER:-o}
service status  dns > /dev/null
rval=$?
if [ $rval -eq 0 ]
then
if [ $DNS_MASTER == `hostname -s` ]
then
echo "1"
else
echo "2"
fi
fi

Comment: It helps if you edit your question and put the script lines in a code block for formatting and readability. From the output given I can quickly see that the test `[ $DNS_MASTER == hostname -s ]` will not succeed (result in error: to many arguments). You'd better use `[ "$DNS_MASTER" == "$(hostname -s)" ]`

Answer (score 1):

The structure: `VALUE=${VAR| |o}` is invalid in dash, bash, ksh and zsh.

**If** the `| |` is actually a `/ /` then it may(?) make sense in bash.

It would mean: replace the first occurrence of an space  by an `o`.

Whether that is a reasonable replacement is another matter. I don't believe it is.

In the code added in the edit, the dots are not valid in a variable name neither in dash, bash or zsh and under very specific conditions in ksh.
This will fail in bash:

```
DNS_MASTER=${TEST.DNS.DNS_MASTER:-o}
```

Also, this test is incorrect, because of white space and because the hostname command is not being executed:

```
if [ $DNS_MASTER == hostname -s ]
```

Use:

```
if [ "$DNS_MASTER" == "$(hostname -s)" ]
```

In all, the code you present could not work correctly in bash, and is puzzling in most shells. Please edit your question to make it relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of a shell-operator that looks like that, is the [bash patch](https://web.archive.org/web/20090409235848/http://home.eol.ca/~parkw) that William Park was maintaining in the years 2004-2008 that came with a few more or less useful extensions to bash3.

Among them was a series a [parameter expansion operators](https://web.archive.org/web/20090409235848/http://home.eol.ca/~parkw/#parameter_expansion) that all started with `${var|...}` some of them reminiscent of `zsh`'s parameter flags (albeit with a completely different syntax).

In that shell, `${var| |o}` would have been parsed as `${var|cmd}`, (meant to be more or less the same as `$(cmd "$var"}`) but would have resulted in a `invalid command` error as that `|o` would not be seen as a valid command name (even if you created a command by that name).